# Cannot find ORMLite annotations from generic Trait

Tags: groovy, ormlite

I have several ORM classes to use with ORMLite. All of them have one static field (the DAO) and a couple of static methods. I want to move these three to a generic Trait, like this:

```
trait ORM<K, V> {

    private static Dao<K, V> dao = null

    @Synchronized
    static Dao getDao() {
        dao = dao ?:  DaoManager.createDao(DatabaseConnection.get(), K)
    }
}
```

This approach won't work, giving the following error

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No fields have a DatabaseField annotation in class java.lang.Object
```

However, if I change the method to an instance method like so

```
trait ORM<K, V> {

    private static Dao<K, V> dao = null

    @Synchronized
    Dao getDao() {
        dao = dao ?:  DaoManager.createDao(DatabaseConnection.get(), this.getClass())
    }
}
```

It works fine, but it doesn't make much sense it to be an instance method.

Any idea on how to make it work in a static context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Groovy can use `this` in static context to reference the class itself. This (no pun intended) solved the problem.

```
@Synchronized
static Dao getDao() {
    dao = dao ?:  DaoManager.createDao(DatabaseConnection.get(), this)
}
```